# Retrieving delay days of the second last payments -- DAX

Tags: dax

I have a table of payments with date of payment, delay days, customer, payment condition. I need to find for every unpaid record the number of delay days of the last payment with the same customer and payment condition.

I have tried this:

```
Predicted delay days = 
VAR customer = MAX('table'[customer])
VAR CONDPAY = MAX('table'[payment condition])
VAR tab = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('table'[delay days]),
    'table'[customer] = customer,
  'table'[payment condition] = CONDPAY,
    NOT ISBLANK('table'[date of payment])
)
RETURN
tab
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, try...

```
Predicted delay days = 
  var lastRow = 
    TOPN(
      1,
      FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('table', 'table'[customer], 'table'[payment condition]),
        NOT ISBLANK('table'[date of payment])
      ),
      [date of payment], DESC
    )

  return CALCULATE( MAX('table'[delay days]), lastRow )
```

As an idea/example, if you wanted to get the average delay of the last three payments then you could have:

```
Predicted delay days Avg = 
  var last3Rows = 
    TOPN(
      3,
      FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('table', 'table'[customer], 'table'[payment condition]),
        NOT ISBLANK('table'[date of payment])
      ),
      [date of payment], DESC
    )

  return AVERAGEX( last3Rows, [delay days] )
```